# How to use external-check command in HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, centos7, haproxy

I am getting issue **External check error, code: 255** while doing external check.

I need to know how external-check command runs a shell script.

https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/external-check-and-chroot/2150.

I have **haproxy.cfg** as follows:

```
global  
    chroot /  
    external-check  
    ....  

backend TCP  
    mode tcp  
    option tcplog  
    option log-health-checks  
    option external-check  
    external-check command /check.sh  
    server serv1 192.168.27.111:9903 check  
    ....
```

Comment: Does your shell script exist relative to the directory you chroot into?  This appears to be what happened to this user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728804/haproxy-external-check-error-code-255

It could also be that your script refers to things that are not in PATH.  By default, PATH is empty for external checks (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-external-check%20path).

Comment: I didn't use jail as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728804/haproxy-external-check-error-code-255. I am using chroot as /. I have also tried by using PATH

Comment: Yes, My script is available in chroot.